# Nautilus 3.6.3: open folder with

Tags: gnome, nautilus, smplayer

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits
Gnome-shell 3.6.2
Nautilus 3.6.3

I have installed SMPlayer. It has a useful (to me) option called "*Add folder content to SMPlayer playlist*" (*or something like that, my native language is spanish*). But Nautilus 3.6.3 doesn't show this option for folders. Has this option gone?

Comment: Just a quick idea but maybe _SMPlayer_ used a script to do this and in new _Nautilus_ the location of user scripts have changed. In such case you could resolve the issue by simply moving the script to the right path (and hopefully informing the _SMPlayer_'s package).

Answer (score 3):

The 'Open with' option for folders seems to have been removed in Nautilus 3.6.3.
It has been reported as a bug.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1026254
There is a patch that fixes the issue if you want to rebuild Nautilus yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patched version of Nautilus. You can install it by pasting the following lines in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/nauty-open
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*works for Ubuntu 13.04 and up*

[Source](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/nauty-open)