# Ubuntu 14.04 `open with` missing on folders

Tags: 14.04, context-menu

Recently I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and I don't see `open with` in the nautilus context menu on the folders. It used to be in 12.04 and I used it for playing music in folders using VLC. How do I get it back in 14.04?

Comment: Is it in the traditional menus that they patched back in in 14.04? Tap `ALT` and then type in `open with` to see if it is there easily...

I know you were asking about how to get it back into the context menu in 14.04 but they might've removed it...in which case you could attempt to install the old version of Nautilus with http://packages.ubuntu.com/ (although it probably won't work)...

Comment: None of these options work.

Comment: What do you mean that you 'used it for playing music in music files' anyway?

Comment: Updated the OP.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/247964/nautilus-3-6-3-open-folder-with/618157

Answer (score 0):

This option was removed, evidently 12.04 was the last version to have this option. There is a bug still open here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1026254