# How to open a folder with an application in nautalius?

Tags: nautilus

I want to be able to right click a folder and select open with Sublime Text Editor / Atom text editor.
How can I do this? 
Here is a picture of the menu that pops up:

[image: Right click menu]

**Side note**: I am running Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for , I want to be able to right click on the `Folder` , not an application and select open with `Sublime Text`

Comment: How can you edit a folder with a text editor?

Comment: I want the text editor to import all the files in that folder by right click , instead of me opening sublime text and select open folder. I have seen people adding this right click feature in OSX and if you install Atom text editor , this option is available by default in Windows , but not in Ubuntu .I want to achieve that feature.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of clarifying it in a comment.

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/247964/nautilus-3-6-3-open-folder-with/618157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some google search I found out that the `Nautilus` used to have `right click open with` menu but it was removed in updated version of it.

As suggested in another answer , one can use that tool but it is too manual .
The alternative could be to use `Nemo` as the file manager .

`$ sudo apt-get install nemo`

Now I have `right click open with` menu .
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom right-click options with this [software](http://www.getdeb.net/install/nautilus-actions).

Here is a nice and easy [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/116807/how-to-easily-add-custom-right-click-options-to-ubuntus-file-manager/) for it.